# How to import icloud notes or restore them?

Tags: iphone, icloud, notes.app

After 10.3 update all of my notes just dissapeared, all my gamesaves too and other stuff. I wouldnt even care because of other stuff on icloud but notes are pretty important for me.

I went to the website version of icloud and found that there is nothing left but notes. I'm even ok with that.

Now the question: how do I restore them on my IPhone? And even more important: how do I import them to my PC in .txt or other text format.

Comment: Just to be sure, you entered your iCloud password when prompted or did you tap 'later'?

Comment: @bjbk No, as system asked I entered my icloud. But there was some stange problem. It wanted me to input some another one password for icloud, but I do not have any other password so I couldnt do anything there, what the heck was that? (and how to backup all the notes?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty strange. After update it didn't work, but now system unlocked buttons in settings to allow syncronisation for all of the apps. I turned on notes and everything else and got my stuff back. Just to point out, maybe some time was needed to allow syncronisation, which is kind of strange, but I am glad I returned my stuff.